# Dependency Injecting Logging in Non-Hosting .NET Console

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core-logging

How can I implement `ILogger` dependency injection (like a hosted app) in a non-hosted Console app? In the code below, I'd like to work like `logTest1`. Is that possible?

Below is my *appsettings.json* - I would prefer to not have to define every class, but this doesn't work anyway.

```
{
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "ClientTestCli.LogTest":  "Trace"
      }
}
```

My Console app Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HandleArgs(args);

        var serviceProvider = ContainerConfiguration.Configure();

        var logTest1 = new LogTest();
        var logTest2 = new LogTest(serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<LogTest>>());
        logTest1.LogStuff();
        logTest2.LogStuff();
    }
}
```

Container configuration:

```
internal static class ContainerConfiguration
{
    public static ServiceProvider Configure()
    {
        return new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(l => l.AddConsole())
            .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(c => c.MinLevel = LogLevel.Trace)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

A test class:

```
internal class LogTest
{
    ILogger<LogTest> logger;
    public LogTest(ILogger<LogTest> logger = null)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogStuff()
    {
        logger?.LogCritical("This is a critical log");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `LogTest` to the service collection and resolve it using the provider and the provider will inject the configured loggers

Refactor your composition root

```
internal static class ContainerConfiguration {
    public static IServiceProvider Configure(Action<IServiceCollection> configuration = null) {
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(logging => {
                 logging.ClearProviders();
                 logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(c => c.MinLevel = LogLevel.Trace);

        configuration?.Invoke(services);

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

And use that at start up

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    HandleArgs(args);

    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = ContainerConfiguration.Configure(services => {
        services.AddTransient<LogTest>();
    });

    LogTest logTest = serviceProvider.GetService<LogTest>();

    logTest.LogStuff();
}
```

If the provider is used, it will take care of building object graph, which includes injecting required dependencies.

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NIDxfX) of a working example.

Comment: @VicF I just ran this using [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NIDxfX) and it executes as expected.

Comment: I figured it out. The program was ending before the log was written to the console. By adding a Thread.Sleep() after the LogTest.LogStuff() call, it worked. Thanks for your help.